# Connection pooling with Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to understand whether the Java client for GCS maintains long-lived / persistent connections. The docs do not mention this.

Does the `Storage` interface support persistent connections out-of-the-box using the following?

```
    // Instantiate a client
    Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().
```

My main concern is the cost of connection creations and potentially having to perform the TLS handshake on every API request. For my use case, I will be frequently uploading / downloading large objects to / from GCS, so I would ideally like to avoid paying the cost of connection creation on every request.

Comment: My understanding is that the transport for API requests is either gRPC or HTTP neither of which maintain connections from the client to the server.  Can you update the question with the back-story.  Are you concerned about the cost of forming a connection to perform a REST request and then bringing it down at the end?

Comment: @Kolban thanks for the response. I added some more context to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Connections are not kept open for subsequent API requests. You can reuse the client (by not instantiating a new one for each request) but each time you issue an upload/download request, a new connection will be created. However, the whole process of creating a new connection is not that "expensive" and therefore shouldn't have a substantial impact.